# Collaborate using GIT - 3rd party libraries

Tags: git, laravel, github, composer-php

I created a `remote repository` and push my project, but `.gitignore` file does not let to upload whole files and folders (e.g. `vendor` and `storage` folder). so if my collaborators want to `clone` my project they can't `fetch` my `laravel` project fully.

My question is how do you share some of files and folders (e.g. vendor, storage, ...) of your laravel projects with your collaborators in remote repositories like github?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's one gotcha here. In repository you should include both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to ensure everyone are using exact same dependencies. Then when you run `composer install` you will be sure that you have exact same versions installed as other developers.

If you don't include `composer.lock` when you use `composer install` you will install latest versions of dependencies from `composer.json` and it might cause everyone will work on different versions of dependencies and it might cause many unexpected problems.

Answer (score 2):

They need to run

```
composer install
```

to install laravel and all dependencies that reside in 'vendor' folder which is ignored.